# How do I know which part of the code is executed when a command of extension is fired in VSCode?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I use an third party extension in VSCode, but have some trouble with it when a certain command is fired.

So I want to debug it, but I don't know which part of the code is executed when the command is fired.

How do I know the part?

Comment: When you now the _command ID_ you can search for that in the source code. If you let us now which extension and which command you refer to, we maybe can provide you more specific help :).

Comment: @HaaLeo Thanks! I want to know the command of open terminal invoked by [vscode-python](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python). I'm glad if you tell me the command, but I'm more glad if you tell me the tools to find the command, thinking of the future.